# Clarification on Pugh's proof of the Extreme Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, proof-explanation, upper-lower-bounds

Here is his proof found in his book Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis:
[image]

In his second case where he says "By continuity at $c$ ...", I don't understand why bringing up the definition of continuity is significant here. If $c$ is the least upper bound of $X$, wouldn't it already imply that l.u.b. $V_{t}$ is less than $M$ since $c\in X$? Is that where I went wrong, in that $c$ does not actually belong in $X$ (well we know this is eventually true in the sentence right after but I mean based off the l.u.b. alone)? Edit: looks like I can't actually conclude that it belongs in X immediately from that fact. but I'm not exactly sure why it is not enough from the fact that $c$ is the l.u.b. of $X$ and what role does the definition of continuity play in solidifying that l.u.b. $V_{t}$ $<M$?

Comment: Right, with only the information "$c$ is the l.u.b. of $X$" you cannot immediately conclude $c \in X$.

Comment: Continuity is essential. Suppose $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and $f(x)=2x$ for $x\in (0,1)$ but $f(0)=f(1)=1$. Then $M=2$ and $c=1$ but we cannot conclude $f(c)=M$ because $f$ is not continuous  at $c.$